How is the memory system configured in avionics computers?
In common memory systems determinism is never achived, meaning that you do not know exactly when are you going to obtain the wanted data, as there can be Cache misses that slow down the data supply. In avionics, determinism must be guaranteed, at least knowing the maximum delay.
Do avionics computers assure no uncertainty, or do they have different memory systems?

I would imagine that the hardware configurations are much like those of any real-time system where errors, delays, etc. are not tolerable. Things like cars, rockets, CNC, etc. all need to have the data now and the hardware is designed to ensure that happens. I don't know exactly how those designs differ from your off-the-shelf home computer, but that might give you more to search on.

There's an easy way to prevent the unpredictability of cache misses: turn off the cache.

A far bigger issue then precise memory timing - which can actually be predicted quite well - is the overall system timing. See Apollo 11 for an example of when this wasn't handle well due to software issues and hardware limitations. The key in general is use a real-time operating system. That can be certain variants of the Linux family, but not your ordinary off-the-shelf workstation or server Linux and definitely not ordinary Windows.

Maybe having a look in the documentation of VxWorks might help

Determinism is out the window the moment you use DRAM due to refresh cycles.

I haven’t designed an avionics computer myself but have worked on many real-time systems.  Essentially the key is to work out the worst-case timings and make sure that the system remains within spec under these conditions.  In the specific case if a cache miss, the worst-case timing is still deterministic because we know how long it will take to identify a cache miss and then how long it will take to perform a read from non-cached memory.  As an aside, since we’re only interested in making sure that worst-case is within spec, there’s not so much incentive to optimise the best-case, so as Jörg has suggested, turning off cache isn’t necessarily a bad idea if it removes other uncertainties.

As you say, there is not much incentive to optimise the best case. But there is incentive to optimise the worst case. And turning off caching does exactly do that

@DeltaLima Turning off cache downgrades the best case to the worst case. It does not change the worst case.

@user71659 It does improve the worst case. With the cache, the worst case is  something like this: 1) search data in cache find out it isn't there 2) load data from slower storage 3) safe data in cache, 4) return data. Without the cache, step 1) and 3) are not there, and thus a) the performance of the worst case is improved, b) the best case is equal to the worst case and so the variation in timing is gone. Both are good things in many real time applications.
